# Dashboard Authorization (self-hosted as a Windows service)

Tags: c#, owin, hangfire

I have a Hangfire instance hosted in a windows service using Topshelf:

```
static void Main()
{
    HostFactory.Run(x =>
    {
        x.Service<Application>(s =>
        {
            s.ConstructUsing(name => new Application());
            s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());
            s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
        });
        x.RunAsLocalSystem();

        x.SetDescription("Hangfire Windows Service Sample");
        x.SetDisplayName("Hangfire Windows Service Sample");
        x.SetServiceName("hangfire-sample");
    });
}

private class Application
{
    private IDisposable host;

    public void Start()
    {
        host = WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:12345");

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Hangfire Server started.");
        Console.WriteLine("Dashboard is available at {0}/hangfire", configSettings.Jobs.EndPoint);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        host.Dispose();
    }
}
```

My StartUp class is pretty basic:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(
        "DefaultConnection",
        new SqlServerStorageOptions {QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)});    

    app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
    {
        AuthorizationFilters = new[] { new AuthorizationFilter() }
    });

    app.UseHangfireServer();
}
```

I'm trying to use a custom authorization filter:

```
public class AuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(IDictionary<string, object> owinEnvironment)
    {
        var context = new OwinContext(owinEnvironment);

        return context.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

I was hoping to use `context.Authentication.User` to authenticate but it always returns null.

Is there any way to make this work for a self-hosted hangfire service?

Comment: You have no any authentication frameworks plugged in, that is why you receive null. Please use [basic authentication](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization#basic-authentication).

Comment: @notlkk - can you please share the solution that worked for you. I am also facing the similar problem with azure worker role. Posted on SO also but for no help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767082/hangfire-dashboard-authorization-in-azure-workerrole

Comment: not solution about it?