# Hangfire dashboard authorization in Azure WorkerRole OR Self Hosted application

Tags: c#, azure-worker-roles, hangfire

It is very recent that I have introduced to Hangfire, and I must say it is awesome.

I am working on an application, wherein I am hosting hangfire in Azure worker role. **Everything works perfect**; the hangfire configuration, job scheduling, dashboard etc. **except configuring authorization to hangfire dashboard**.

I have added an `OwinStartup` class where I have configuring hangfire dashboard. I have used my custom implementation of `IAuthorizationFilter` and an `OwinMiddleware`, anticipating that user should now be prompted to provide credentials while accessing hangfire dashboard. But for no help, and it keep giving me `403` response when trying to access the dashboard. :(

It works perfectly alright if I don't use authorization filter option while configuring dashboard, but then everyone could access it.

This is my Startup class -

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWelcomePage("/");

        app.Use(typeof(AuthenticationMiddleware));

        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
        {
            AuthorizationFilters = new[] { new MyAuthorization() }
        });
    }
```

I have written OWIN middleware i.e. `AuthenticationMiddleware` as suggested  [here](https://lbadri.wordpress.com/2013/07/13/basic-authentication-with-asp-net-web-api-using-owin-middleware/)

...and my custom `IAuthorizationFilter`

```
public class MyAuthorization : IAuthorizationFilter
{
     public bool Authorize(IDictionary<string, object> owinEnvironment)
     {
         var context = new OwinContext(owinEnvironment);

         // Allow all authenticated users to see the Dashboard 
         return context.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
     }
}
```

This is how I am configuring dashboard in `OnStart` method of my worker role. ([ref](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/host-owin-in-an-azure-worker-role))

```
var endpoint = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["WorkerRoleEndpoint"];
string baseUri = String.Format("{0}://{1}", endpoint.Protocol, endpoint.IPEndpoint);//http://127.0.0.1:81/hangfire

owinApp = WebApp.Start<HangfireDashboardStartup>(new StartOptions(url: baseUri));
```

*I guess the solution for hangfire dashboard in self hosted applicatinon should work as well*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following nuget package come to rescue for basic authentication -

**Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.BasicAuthentication**

The package is available here - 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.BasicAuthentication/)

Get this package and simply call the following in your *owin startup* class, instead of your custom middlewawre -

```
app.UseBasicAuthentication("SomeName", ValidateUser);
```

...where `ValidateUser` is the function to validate the user.

```
    private Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> ValidateUser(string id, string secret)
    {
        if (id == secret) //Dummy validation, modify it accordingly
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, id),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Foo")
            };
            return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Claim>>(claims);
        }
        return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Claim>>(null);
    }
```

And your are done! Now when you will access hangfire dashboard, you will be prompted for credentials.